# Plugin that can read and modifying host application objects (MEF)

Tags: c#, mef

How i can create plugin that can read and modifying host application objects with MEF?
For example, host application has TextBox object. I need create plugin that can read text from TextBox and modified it.

In this example i'm try access to string:

In host application i'm write follow:

```
        string _str_test;
        [Export("str_test")]
        public string str_test
        {
            get { return _str_test; }
            set { _str_test = value; }
        }
```

In plugin i'm write follow:

```
        string _str_test;
        [Import("str_test")]
        public string str_test
        {
            get { return _str_test; }
            set { _str_test = value; }
        }
```

But str_test is null.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `CompositionContainer`.  The container should create the plugins.  It should also create the classes in the host application that have imports, if that is possible.  If not you can call `container.SatisfyImports(hostObject)` to have the imports on an object satisfied.